# How to import a Kotlin Library in IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

So i want to use the Serialization Library in my kotlin project, and from what i can gather from this [page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#example-json-serialization), i must use this: "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2", to do so, now i use "IntelliJ" as my build system, so i went to the project structure, and in libraries, clicked the + sign, clicked on "From Maven" and put this as the link to the library, and it downloaded it and i set it as a dependency of my project, it even shows as a external library, like this:
[image]

But when i try to import the lib, it gives error:
[image]

Comment: Instructions should be available here. You probably need to add the plugin declaration. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#example-json-serialization

Comment: @Chris the thing is i have used IntelliJ as build setting and not gradle or maven, but i've decided to shift to gradle cuz using IntelliJ build just makes everything more difficult, though i have been having problems with Gradle as well,will update link here when i post the question

Comment: Update: nvm it worked, i was basically trying to run gradle with jdk-18, when it only supports till jdk-16, so i changed it and it worked, anyways thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can indeed use IntelliJ IDEA as a build system without maven or gradle, but I don't think this is a supported way to use kotlinx-serialization.

I'd advise to pick either maven or gradle as your build system for your project (this can be done through IntelliJ, just create a new project and pick either one).

Then you can just follow the relevant paragraph at https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#setup for either maven or gradle.

Comment: ahh i see, guess i'll use gradle, i actually have tried to do it but hit some errors and gave up, i'll write another question as to the problem, will update with link when posted. i just feel like there isn't enough documentation and help online about all this when compared to say languages like C++, or even newer languages like python. Anyways, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Edit: I must admit to being kinda dumb, i was trying to run jdk 18 with gradle, but it only supports till version 16, so i did that and it worked, yeah.....

Comment: The latest version of gradle supports up to JDK 17, not 16: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html This is the newest LTS version and thus most likely the JDK that you want to be using. I think you can use the RC versions of gradle 7.5 if you want to use JDK 18 though.